# Adding public IP for existing virtual machine scale set

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm-scale-set

I have an existing virtual machine scale set. Currently I have one virtual machine there. I would like to update the scale set and add a public IP to the virtual machine or somehow create a load balancer that will allow me to "access" the virtual machine from the outside. I am new to azure so I have no idea how it all works.

Any ideas/help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a load balancer with the public IP, then add the virtual machine scale set into the backend pool of the load balancer. Finally, create the NAT rules for each instance. Create the load balancer following the steps in [Create a Basic Load Balancer by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/quickstart-create-basic-load-balancer-portal).

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to create all of this, but sadly I still cant connect from the public ip:port to the internal service on the machine. Maybe it's a firewall problem? or something that has to be configured in the portal? I've added a load balancing rule, and updated the network security group policy to allow the port.

Comment: Yes, you also should check the NSG associated with your VM nic of the subnet. For the virtual machine scale set, you can add the load balancer rules with the port for your application to access outside.